# I can`t understand what I`m doing wrong

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

```
NMaximize[{99.3*a1 + 73.5*a2 + 60.25*a3 + 23.53*a4 + 40.13*a5 + 
   30.63*a6 + 40.66*a7 + 59.75*a8 + 65.42*a9 + 20.71*a10 + 
   126.52*a11 + 54.09*a12 + 40.66*a13 + 40.65*a14 + 33.08*a15 + 
   44.63*a16 + 27.79*a17 + 68.64*a18 + 36.74*a19 + 24.28*a20, 
  a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13 +
      a14 + a15 + a16 + a17 + a18 + a19 + a20 == 1 && a1 >= 0 && 
   a2 >= 0 && a3 >= 0 && a4 >= 0 && a5 >= 0 && a6 >= 0 && a7 >= 0 && 
   a8 >= 0 && a9 >= 0 && a10 >= 0 && a11 >= 0 && a12 >= 0 && 
   a13 >= 0 && a14 >= 0 && a15 >= 0 && a16 >= 0 && a17 >= 0 && 
   a18 >= 0 && a19 >= 0 && a20 >= 0 && 
   14993.32*((a1)^2) + 1755.69*((a2)^2) + 1589.36*((a3)^2) + 
     65.24*((a4)^2) + 515.95*((a5)^2) + 312.67*((a6)^2) + 
     513.08*((a7)^2) + 1489.76*((a8)^2) + 818.14*((a9)^2) + 
     185.35*((a10)^2) + 8185.18*((a11)^2) + 780.3*((a12)^2) + 
     740.55*((a13)^2) + 269.12*((a14)^2) + 484.92*((a15)^2) + 
     713.26*((a16)^2) + 264.21*((a17)^2) + 1319*((a18)^2) + 
     480.05*((a19)^2) + 203.66*((a20)^2) + 1147.52*a1*a2 - 
     1237.04*a1*a3 + 1648.1*a1*a4 + 872.82*a1*a5 + 1491.5*a1*a6 + 
     3084.06*a1*a7 + 890.06*a1*a8 - 1807.8*a1*a9 + 1866*a1*a10 + 
     17149.98*a1*a11 + 3071.4*a1*a12 + 922.38*a1*a13 + 
     2804.84*a1*a14 - 983.98*a1*a15 + 2240.68*a1*a16 + 
     1078.78*a1*a17 + 4560.28*a1*a18 + 3269.3*a1*a19 + 
     1265.3*a1*a20 - 268.94*a2*a3 - 24.99*a2*a4 + 1322*a2*a5 + 
     1172.24*a2*a6++ 614.7*a2*a7 + 2711.82*a2*a8 - 805.38*a2*a9 + 
     380.3*a2*a10 + 1294.7*a2*a11 + 479.08*a2*a12 + 1667.14*a2*a13 + 
     32.72*a2*a14 + 613.44*a2*a15 + 1756.2*a2*a16 + 685.5*a2*a17 + 
     2436.32*a2*a18 + 872.26*a2*a19 + 887.86*a2*a20 - 49.98*a3*a4 - 
     400.54*a3*a5 - 63.52*a3*a6 - 921.9*a3*a7 - 174.52*a3*a8 + 
     1069.54*a3*a9 - 230.2*a3*a10 - 738.34*a3*a11 - 189.76*a3*a12 - 
     308.5*a3*a13 - 250.8*a3*a14 + 293.78*a3*a15 - 330.02*a3*a16 - 
     187.36*a3*a17 - 281.84*a3*a18 - 388.62*a3*a19 - 263.1*a3*a20 - 
     4.16*a4*a5 + 72.34*a4*a6 + 157.8*a4*a7 - 7.78*a4*a8 - 
     89.04*a4*a9 + 138.22*a4*a10 + 2631.61*a4*a11 + 194.48*a4*a12 + 
     15*a4*a13 + 168.42*a4*a14 - 88.4*a4*a15 + 118.26*a4*a16 + 
     78.36*a4*a17 + 257.72*a4*a18 + 204.92*a4*a19 + 58.26*a4*a20 + 
     376.82*a5*a6 + 307*a5*a7 + 929.6*a5*a8 - 769.88*a5*a9 + 
     213.42*a5*a10 + 962.52*a5*a11 + 321.72*a5*a12 + 595.64*a5*a13 + 
     14.28*a5*a14 + 334.66*a5*a15 + 843.44*a5*a16 + 560.44*a5*a17 + 
     1069.02*a5*a18 + 482.6 a5*a19 + 354.58*a5*a20 + 3192.92*a6*a7 + 
     1209*a6*a8 - 322.26*a6*a9 + 243.3*a6*a10 + 1529.02*a6*a11 + 
     291.28*a6*a12 + 753.8*a6*a13 + 105.96*a6*a14 + 159.84 a6*a15 + 
     664.58*a6*a16 + 255.72*a6*a17 + 1020.76*a6*a18 + 468.36*a6*a19 + 
     412.32*a6*a20 + 511.1*a7*a8 - 349.64*a7*a9 + 408.16*a7*a10 + 
     2631.64*a7*a11 + 422.36 a7*a12 + 427.98*a7*a13 + 524.74*a7*a14 - 
     223.44*a7*a15 + 671.46*a7*a16 + 270.06*a7*a17 + 824.64*a7*a18 + 
     687.19*a7*a19 + 299.48*a7*a20 - 609.64*a8*a9 + 333.6*a8*a10 + 
     1813.08*a8*a11 + 211.38*a8*a12 + 1798.22*a8*a13 - 24.56*a8*a14 + 
     569.16*a8*a15 + 1514.84*a8*a16 + 532.04 a8a17 + 1893.6*a8*a18 + 
     728.74*a8*a19 + 801.14*a8*a20 - 239.94*a9*a10 - 1136.78*a9*a11 - 
     208.86*a9*a12 - 341.46*a9*a13 - 162.28*a9*a14 - 162.48*a9*a15 - 
     555.32*a9*a16 - 488.58*a9*a17 - 893.24*a9*a8 - 446.96 a9*a19 - 
     322.82*a9*a20 + 1772.86*a10*a11 + 375.2*a10*a12 + 
     312.68*a10*a13 + 263.98*a10*a14 - 90.44*a10*a15 + 
     426.8*a10*a16 + 194.72*a10*a17 + 602.38*a10*a18 + 
     456.64*a10*a19 + 252.68*a10*a20 + 2355*a11*a12 + 
     1454.18*a11*a13 + 1609.78*a11*a14 - 424.58*a11*a15 + 
     2314.86*a11*a16 + 1479.7*a11*a17 + 3344.62*a11*a18 + 
     3165.1*a11*a19 + 1156.32*a11*a20 + 191.74*a12*a13 + 
     387.92*a12*a14 - 0.54*a12*a15 + 0.76*a12*a16 + 0.7*a12*a17 + 
     0.94*a12*a16 + 0.98*a12*a19 + 0.58*a12*a20 + 53.44*a13*a14 + 
     252.8*a13*a15 + 1014.84*a13*a16 + 358.62*a13*a17 + 
     1153.68*a13*a18 + 606.58*a13*a19 + 562.34*a13*a20 - 
     230.12 a14*a15 + 239.54*a14*a16 + 112.12*a14*a17 + 
     469.42 a14a18 + 301.86*a14*a19 + 107.48*a14*a20 + 
     260.34*a15*a16 + 213.38*a15*a17 + 141.7*a15*a18 - 
     107.38 a15*a19 + 77.1*a15*a20 + 597*a16*a17 + 1478.04*a16*a18 + 
     802.58*a16*a19 + 22.02*a16*a20 + 695.36*a17*a18 + 
     379.72*a17*a19 + 182.28*a17*a20 + 1067.86 a18*a19 + 
     759.28*a18*a20 + 454.28*a19*a20 <= 10}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, 
  a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, 
  a20}]
```

And I get this:

> Increment::rvalue: a6 is not a variable with a value, so its value
>   cannot be changed Set::write: Tag RandomReal in RandomReal[] is
>   Protected. >> NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not
>   valid:
>   {a1+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16+a17+a18+a19+a2+a20+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8+a9==1,a1>=0,a10>=0,<<16>>,a8>=0,a9>=0,14993.3
>   a1^2+1866 a1 a10+185.35 a10^2+17150. a1 a11+1772.86 a10 a11+8185.18
>   a11^2+3071.4 a1 a12+375.2 a10 a12+2355 a11 a12+780.3 a12^2+922.38 a1
>   a13+312.68 a10 a13+1454.18 a11 a13+191.74 a12 a13+740.55 a13^2+2804.84
>   a1 a14+<<24>>+260.34 a15 a16+713.26 a16^2+1078.78 a1 a17+194.72 a10
>   a17+1479.7 a11 a17+0.7 a12 a17+358.62 a13 a17+112.12 a14 a17+213.38
>   a15 a17+597 a16 a17+264.21 a17^2+4560.28 a1 a18+602.38 a10 a18+3344.62
>   a11 a18+1153.68 a13 a18+<<157>><=10}. Constraints should be
>   equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the
>   variables. >>

Comment: Wow. A wall of numbers. Could you try and format your question so it is more readable? Start by describing the problem you are experiencing. It is certainly a good idea to provide the code that's giving you trouble, but enclose it in back-quotes, and provide some line breaks.

Comment: About a quarter of the way down, you have a typo:  `1172.24*a2*a6++`.  Mathematica interprets `a6++` as "increment a6 by 1", which is why it's complaining that it's not a variable with a value.  Also, near the bottom you have a term `469.42 a14a18`, which is not the same as `469.42*a14*a18`.  (The code still doesn't work after you correct this, though; see my answer below for another approach.)

Comment: There is also an `a8a17`. Really, you need to find your own typos; this is not what the site is meant for. With those fixed you will receive other messages, but the input runs, at least, giving `{35.3017, {a1 -> -0.0390144, a2 -> 0., a3 -> 0., a4 -> 0.459037, a5 -> 0.0842617, a6 -> 0., a7 -> 0., a8 -> 0.0740445, a9 -> 0.173333, a10 -> 0., a11 -> 0., a12 -> 0., a13 -> 0., a14 -> 0.161749, a15 -> 0.0476306, a16 -> 0., a17 -> 0.0379065, a18 -> 0., a19 -> 0., a20 -> 0.00105315}}` as an output along with a message saying that the constraint was not accurately met (value is about 18).

Answer (score 1):

To get around the "wall of code" problem, here's another approach:  Define an upper-diagonal matrix with the coefficients of the polynomial in it, and use dot products to generate the polynomial.  For example, if you want to define the polynomial $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2$, you could write this as:

```
mat = {{a, b},{0, c}};
varvec = {x,y};
polynom = Expand[varvec.mat.varvec]

(* a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 *)
```

So, as a 3D example of what you're trying to do:

```
mat = {{5,2,0},{0,3,0},{0,0,4}};
varvec = {x,y,z};
polynom = Expand[varvec.mat.varvec]
NMaximize[{3 x + 4 y - 2 z, x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x + y + z == 1 
  && polynom <= 2}, {x, y, z}]

(* 5 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2 + 4 z^2 *)

(* {3.23914, {x -> 0.25224, y -> 0.66299, z -> 0.0847704}} *)
```

This method has the advantage that the terms in the polynomial are generated by Mathematica itself, and Mathematica doesn't make transcription errors when defining 210-term polynomials.